# Is there a way to add an analytical store to an existing Azure Cosmos DB container?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

All the examples I can find show how to add the analytical store while creating a new container. I have a container that already has data in it. I want to add the analytical store capability without having to export the data, drop and re-create the container, and re-import the data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/configure-synapse-link#create-analytical-ttl), I think it's impossible to achieve it now. And as the doc said, for containers that have been created, what should be done is creating a new one and migrate data from your exisitng containers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes [this is possible now for SQL API containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/configure-synapse-link#update-analytical-ttl).

[image]